# Android Studio App don't work on Lollipop or KitKat only on 6.0

Tags: java, jsoup, android-4.4-kitkat, android-studio-2.3

The App shows the text from a Url. I used Jsoup for this project and the app works very good on devices with API 23 but I would like to support devices from KitKat and Lollipop too. The Buttons and the TextViews work but the internet text is not there.
I hope somebody can help me....

This is my project's build.gradle file:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.schlauies.supertext"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
}
```

This is the XMl File:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.schlauies.supertext.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tx1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the Java code:

```js
package com.schlauies.supertext;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;

//import orgs.Document;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView texx ;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         texx =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tx1);
         Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);

        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new doit().execute();


            }
        });
    }


    public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        String words = "";
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://vertretung.esy.es/gust.txt").get();
                words = doc.text();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            texx.setText(words);


        }
    }
}
```

If somebody had questions please ask  :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to add this permission in Manifest file

> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Can you make your answer more explicit?  I know very little about Android programming and while I have found the AndroidManifest.xml file, I don't have any permissions in there, so I don't know where to add your line.